# reCAPTCHA v3 with Firebase phone AUTH

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

Does Firebase Phone auth support reCAPTCHA v3?

We are having a bunch of issues with firebase phone auth.

1. Users get the challenge too often
2. In a mobile device where the div element is scrollable. If the user is at the bottom of the page and requested authentication, the challenge appears on top. The user doesn't know that they have to solve the challenge.
3. If the user doesn't solve the challenge by clicking outside, the challenge doesn't come again and the phone auth starts failing.

Would be great if community can share some solutions used by the community to solve these issues.

Thank you!